# Cannot locate correct line where error is being thrown

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have noted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593197/what-is-the-default-precision-and-scale-for-a-number-in-oracle) that the expected width of a number data type is dynamically set to whatever you need up to a precision of 21 bytes, however I can see in my code that the line

```
MAX_LENGTH CONSTANT NUMBER := 2000;
```

is throwing the error:

```
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "DBAuser.MAKE_VIEWS", line 58
```

Am I misinterpreting the error, or is it possible that the CONSTANT modifier is changing something that I don't expect?  Is there a system level setting which can change the default width of number types?

Edited to reflect more accurate title - issue is that I am looking at what I think is line 58 but it's really not

Comment: The error is not on the line 1 it is on line 58, what has on that line? at this object : `DBAuser.MAKE_VIEWS`

Comment: @JorgeCampos yeah the line I've copied there is line 58 - I understand that :)

Comment: The assignment you've shown has nothing to do with a character conversion, which is what's failing. I've found that sometimes the line number reported isn't the actual failing line. Do you have any `TO_CHAR` calls, or are you concatenating a number onto a character string somewhere?

Comment: Query `USER_SOURCE` to get the real line 58

Comment: thanks @JeffreyKemp - recompiled packages and queried the user source as suggested - had to trace back a few files but the culprit was found on a line which made much more sense than the one I was looking at...you want to re-write your comment as an answer and I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query `USER_SOURCE` to determine exactly which line the error is complaining about.