# Looking for up to date documentation on Oracle SQL Number DATA to answer scale question

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been assuming based on old posts I found here and elsewhere that a NUMBER data type with no scale specified defaults to zero. However, when I look at our data on our server, I see rational numbers (read non-integers) even with no scale specified. Is this expected behavior?

To give some context, I am a technical writer and I am documenting various things associated with the data we house. I have been assuming that all NUMBERS with no scale specified have been integers. If this is incorrect, I'll need to update my documentation.

I have basically used the following link as a citation for my reasoning concerning scale, but now I believe that it is outdated. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593197/what-is-the-default-precision-and-scale-for-a-number-in-oracle#)

I have also read the oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313). The last link also states that if no scale is specified, then the default is set to zero.

Comment: You mean [the current documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78)?

Comment: I guess I lack the know-how for how to determine if its the current documentation or not. So, to make sure I am reading this correctly, all NUMBERs with no p/s specified are float-point numbers?

Comment: Yes, essentially, as Gordon said.

Comment: "Up to date" documentation in this case is not really meaningful. Precision and scale have worked the same way going back at least a very large number of versions; and in each version, the documentation uses the same confusing language (which is then explained very well in Gordon's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Oracle documentation is misleading.  If no precision *and* no scale is specified, then the number is stored as-is; the default to `0` scale only occurs when there is a specified precision.

So, the following code stores the first few digits of pi:

```
create table t (n number);

insert into t(n) values (3.14159265358979);
```

But this does not:

```
create table t2 (n number(5));

insert into t2(n) values (3.14159265358979);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=027f1c716e0ba0a68e953df6b2f3c68c) is a db<>fiddle illustrating this.

This is rather indelibly marked in my memory, from a fun time porting an Oracle database to BigQuery (which did not even have numeric at the time).  The Oracle `number` data type was one of the most difficult parts of the transition.  In the end, we needed to move that into strings.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. So then all my NUMBER data types with no p/s specified will be rationals, but might only be integers by convention.

Comment: @MatthewYocum . . . Yes.  In my case, I discovered that these numbers were sometimes used for codes, that the codes on occasion had decimal points, and zeros after the decimal point were significant.